# React : Action creator not calling reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am making an async call in my action creator and calling my reducer with the result, but for some reason i could not fathom the reducer is not being called.

actions.js (action and action creator)

```
export const GET_FORMS = 'GET_FORMS'

export function getForms() {
  $.get("server url", function(result) {
   return {
    type: GET_FORMS,
    formlist: result.data.forms
   }   
  })
 }
```

reducers.js

```
import { GET_FORMS } from '../actions/actions'

export default function formAction(state = {forms:[]}, action) {
  console.log("received action"+action.type)
  switch (action.type) {

    case GET_FORMS:
      console.log("Action:"+action);
      return Object.assign({},state,{
       forms:action.formlist
      })

   default:
    return state
 }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import auth from '../auth'
import FormTable from '../components/FormTable'
import * as FormActions from '../actions/actions'


class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {forms: []};
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  // for some reason if i write this.props.actions.getForms () i get an error
  // Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for 
  // async actions.
  FormActions.getForms();
 }

 render() {
  const {forms,actions} = this.props
  console.log(forms);
  return (
    <FormTable results={forms} actions = {actions} /> 
  )
 }
}

App.PropTypes = {
  forms: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps() {
 const {
  forms:forms
 } = {forms:[]}

 return {
  forms
 }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
  actions: bindActionCreators(FormActions, dispatch)
 }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few things here.

1. Your action creator doesn't return the action that it's creating. `$.get` does not return an action, so mapping it to `dispatch` isn't productive.

   Reasonably, this may lead confused about how to return an action from an async action creator. Since it's async, by nature it can't return the final result (unless you're using es7 `async` `await`). The pattern you're attempting is identical to this:

   ```
   class App extends Component {
     ...
     componentDidMount() {
       // Instead of calling getForms, do the same directly
       $.get(url, function(res) {
         return { type: GET_FORMS, forms: res };
       });
     }

     render() { ... }
   }
   ```

   From the `$.get` api we know that `$.get` returns a [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)
   , not any kind of action. So you have to use the result in the callback its self--you can't just return it. Here's an example of what `componentDidMount` could then look like (note the callback is bound to `this`):

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     $.get(url, function(res) {
       this.props.dispatch({ type: GET_FORMS, forms: res });
     }.bind(this))
   }
   ```
2. *Doing* async in your component or action creator is an anti-pattern, or at least discouraged. In this case, you're *defining* the async inside an action creator, which is great. But you're *executing* the async operation as well, which is bad. Instead you should employ some kind of middleware to handle async operations. Middleware are just functions that take actions and do stuff with them after they are dispatched, and the most common one for this purpose is `redux-thunk`. Using `redux-thunk`, you simply return a function that accepts `dispatch` as an argument. In this case, your action creator would look like this:

   ```
   export function getForms() {
     return function(dispatch) {
       $.get(url, function(result) {
         dispatch({ type: GET_FORMS, forms: result });
       })
     }
   }
   ```

   This is very similar to what you're already doing, except that you're creating a `thunk`--which is just a function that defines another function for execution later--instead of actually doing the async operation *now*, you're defining it for execution later.
3. You're not actually dispatching anything.

   The simplest problem to fix, but definitely a barrier :) In `componentDidMount`, you're calling the action creator that you've imported, but you're not calling `dispatch`. You're 50% of the way there though, in that you passed the action creators to `connect`, but even though you did that, you didn't call the bound action creators that `connect` passes into prop--you called the unbound ones.

   So instead of calling `FormActions.getForms()`, you need to call `this.props.actions.formActions()`. The former is not bound, but the latter is. Calling the latter is the same as doing `this.props.dispatch(FormActions.getForms())`.
4. And finally: you don't need to define `mapDispatchToProps` in this case. You can pass objects to that parameter of `connect`. See below:

   ```
   // Instead of this
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

   // do this:
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, FormActions)(App);
   // creates the bound action creator 'this.props.getForms()'
   ```

   This one is mostly a style choice, but I think this is a good pattern :) For multiple action creator source objects, you can do this:

   ```
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, { ...FormActions, ...UserActions })(App);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on how the redux flow works I was able to get the reducer capture the action from the action creator and using the logger i was able to verify there is a state change. But in the render method of App.js the forms array/object still seems to be empty. Am i doing something wrong in mapstatetoprops.

Comment: yes - mapStateToProps will always return an empty array. You're using destructuring assignment so const { forms: forms } = { forms: []}; will always be forms = []. If you're using connect, you need to be specifying which part of the global state you want to be injecting into the component. You can read more about usage with react here: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: Yup. I got that i wasnt mapping the forms to the state and hence wasnt able to get the changes.  The link helped me map my state to the forms and display get the data in my render method.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!  That explanation was superb and so incredibly helpful.  Learning from docs is one thing but learning by thoughtfully reviewing someone's attempt is quite another.  ...and I appreciate your nonjudgmental, helpful tone.  Truly.  This post took me from, "huh?" to    r e d u x   w o r k i n g  (yeah)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the redux-thunk middle ware:
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

essentially as your code stands - you aren't returning an FSA compliant action (and actually aren't returning anything right now). You need to thunk the dispatch and then return the result of the promise.

More on async action creators here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html